# Return the new created Document ID after the document is created in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

First of all, thank you so much for your time and help.

I have a method defined within a class to add data onto the Firestore database as shown below:

```
class DatabaseService {

Future<DocumentReference> addData() async {
    DocumentReference doc = await _userCollection.add({
      'firstName': 'Mickey',
      'lastName': 'Mouse',
      'age': 10,
      'languages': ['English'],
      'timestamp': FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    });
    return doc;
  }
}
```

When I invoke this method on tap of a raised button, which is within a stateful class. It works perfectly fine as expected and creates a new document within the Firestore database. I would like the addData method to return the document ID of the newly created document, I'm not sure how to return and display the document ID.

This is how the code within my onPressed event looks:

```
onPressed: () {
                      Future<DocumentReference> doc =
                          DatabaseService().addData();
                      print(doc);
                    },
```

It just prints the following line in the console:

```
Instance of 'Future<DocumentReference>'
```

When I try printing the id property, it is giving me a compilation error.

```
print(doc.id);
```

I'm using the latest version of Firebase Firestore packages as listed below:

```
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  firebase: ^7.3.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you’re getting `Instance of 'Future<DocumentReference>'` instead of the value is that it is a Future. Future need to be awaited before they have a value, or an error. You should have something like this instead

```
onPressed: () async {
  DocumentReference doc = await DatabaseService().addData();
  print(doc);
},
```

I strongly recommend you read more about [asynchronous programming: futures, async, await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await). It will save you lots of headaches in the future, no pun intended :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but documentID has been deprecated in the latest version of the cloud_firestore package with id. But I'm unable to see id property at all when I try to print it from the calling function, whereas it works completely fine when I use it within the addData method.

Comment: You’re right sorry still getting used to that. I corrected my answer

Comment: Also your function returns the wrong type. I added the corrected function in my answer.

Comment: If my answer is useful please take a second accept it and upvote. Otherwise let me know why it’s not working you.